# Adding Excel file to Outlook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Having tried all resources while googling the issue, I can't figure what's wrong.

Using the simple line of code

```
Attachment.Add ("C:\Users\320006190\test.txt")
```

is not working to add a file, Despite that file exiting in that exact location.

Comment: Appears to be a typo Attachments.Add with an s. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strLocation As String

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hello World!"

        strLocation = "C:\Users\Desktop\location\your_file_name.xlsx"
        .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, more than likely a small syntax error that I was unable to pick up from looking at it too much. thanks!